# Programmatically adding installable time-driven trigger for stand-alone webapp

Tags: google-apps-script

I want my stand-alone web app script to run everyday between 14:00 and 15:00 GMT +4:30 (Asia/Tehran). It should open a spreadsheet and check a certain cell.

So far I have the following:

```
function addTrigger() {
  var ssid = "My SpreadSheet ID";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  var everyDay = ScriptApp.newTrigger("checkExitTime")
```

At this stage, both the forSpreadSheet(String key) and timeBased() show up in the list of available methods. But when I chain one, the other becomes unavailable. So if I use the forSpreadSheet method, the timeBased() methods vanish and the only methods that show up are create() onChange(), onEdit(), onOpen(), and on onFormSubmit(). How can I have both?

I would like to have something like:

```
var everyDay = ScriptApp.newTrigger("checkExitTime")
            .timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(14).inTimezone("Asia/Tehran")
            .forSpreadSheet(ss)
            .create()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScriptApp.newTrigger` returns a [TriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder) class which further classifies triggers into different type of triggers. So when you will call `ScriptApp.newTrigger("yourFn").timeBaesd()` will return you a [ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) class whose methods will return you the same ClockTriggerBuilder class for method chaining, but you will remain in that class.

To access another type of trigger, in your case `.forSpreadSheet(ss)` will return you [SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder) class whose builder methods will return the same class for method chaining.

In your code:

```
var everyDay = ScriptApp.newTrigger("checkExitTime")
        .timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(14).inTimezone("Asia/Tehran")
        .forSpreadSheet(ss)
        .create();
```

Using `.forSpreadSheet` is unnecessary and does not make any sense since you cannot chain the two methods as they are not available in the object returned.

I reckon what you wanted to do is to manipulate the spreadsheet when time based  trigger runs; so you should create a time driven trigger and do your task in its handler function:

```
var everyDay = ScriptApp.newTrigger("checkExitTime")
        .timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(14).inTimezone("Asia/Tehran")
        .create();

//// Handler function of time driven trigger
function checkExitTime(e){
    var ssid = "My SpreadSheet ID";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
    //// do your task
}
```

However if you also want spreadsheet triggers like `onOpen()`, `onEdit()` etc, you have to initiate them separately like ["this"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newtriggerfunctionname).

```
 // Creates an edit trigger for a spreadsheet identified by ID.
 var ssid = "My SpreadSheet ID";
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
     .forSpreadsheet(ssid)
     .onEdit()
     .create();

 // your onEdit event handler
 function myFunction(event){
      // your code..
 }
```

will execute `myFunction` when edit event will occur on your spreadsheet.

Comment: Alright, now I see my folly! I'll try it and post the result here. Thanks for the illuminating answer.

Comment: That's great mate, you can surely share the results here. If you think your problem is solved, you can close your question by check marking the most  helpful answer on your post, thanks.

Comment: It worked beautifully. I am now getting those emails regularly. Thanks a million.